# Is it wrong to set a Firebase Firestore document with an e-mail ID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in which users can subscribe their e-mails to. In order to prevent multiple e-mails that are equal, and to not query, I am wondering if it's possible to set the ID of a document to be an e-mail string (which contains characters such as `@` and `.`)

I know I could do it through something like:

`Firestore.firestore().collection("waitlist").document(email)`

But under the hood, is there any problem with having a `documentID` that contains the aforementioned characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may not be "wrong", technically speaking, but I would avoid it for the following reasons:

1. Email addresses are typically case-insensitive.  Document IDs are always exact.
2. Peoples' email addresses may to change over time.  Document IDs can never change.  To deal with an email address change, you'd have to create a new document with the contents of the old document, then delete the old document.

If you simply want to find a document based on an email address, just do a query for documents with the field that contains the address.  You might want to store the address in a fully lowercase string to avoid case sensitivity issues.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do so. See [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) for the constraints on document IDs. There is no constraint against "@" or "."